# search for a line in a file in perl

Tags: perl

I want to look for specific lines in **tobecompared** file,which are **not available** in my **SourceFile**.I have a mistake that I cant find

```
open INPUT, "SourceFile";
@input = <INPUT>;
close INPUT;

open FILE, "tobecompared";
while (<FILE>){

    if (/>/) {

        push(@array, $_);
    }
}
foreach $temp (@array) {

    $temp =~ s/>//;
    $temp =~ s/\s.*\n$//g;

    if  (@input !~ $temp){

        print $temp."\n";                   
    }
}
close FILE;
```

Comment: If you're on a Unix machine, why not just use diff / vimdiff?

Comment: I need to process it afterward,this is just a part of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you code

```
if (@input !~ $temp){

    print $temp."\n";                   
}
```

The variable `@input` is evaluated in scalar context, which returns the number of elements in `@input`. So you print you line unless the number of lines in SourceFile is matched by any line in  tobecompared interpreted as a regular expression after some mangling.

Except for any mangling you need to do, the standard solution to the problem "print all lines in fileA which isn't in fileB" is to read all lines in fileB into hash keys and then use exists. That is:

```
my %seen;
open my $fh, '<', "fileB"
    or die "Ooops";

while (<$fh>) {

    $seen{$_} = 1;
}
close $fh;

open my $source, '<', "fileA"
    or die "Ooops";

while (<$source>) {

    print $_ unless exists $seen{$_};
}
close $source;
```

You can of course add any mangling before adding lines to %seen and before testing for existence in %seen.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot match an array with `!~` (`Applying pattern match (m//) to @array will act on scalar(@array) at d.pl line 24`) but you can join the array and match against it:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $input = join("", @input);

# ....

if  ($input !~ $temp){

    print $temp."\n";                   
}
```

Comment: With this solution, the array ABC, CDE would match element CC.